# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2x)}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x \in (0, 2\pi)$. Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2x)}{n}$ convergent? My guess is: YES and I would like to use Dirichlet test: however I have troubles proving that the partial sums $\cos(x)+\cos(4x)+...+\cos(n^2x)$ are bounded due to the lack of the simple formula for this sum. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the partial sums are bounded. My guess is that there are some $x$ with annoying continued fraction expansion. However, I think the set of such $x$ is measure $0$.

Comment: You could look at the following question first: Is there an x such that $\cos(n^2x)>\epsilon$ for all n for some epsilon >0. If that is the case (which looks likely to me even though I can‘t imediatly see such an element) you can lower bound that sum by the harmonic sum which is divergent. Therefore for that x the sum would be divergent as well

Comment: At least sometimes it is convergent: take $x=\pi$.

Comment: And sometimes it is divergent: take $x=\frac{\pi}2$. For odd indeces $n$ the fraction vanishes, for even indeces $n$ it is $\frac 1n$.

Comment: It is the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function. Carleson's theorem implies that it converges a.e.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for joining the discussion after two years but I wanted to share this rather interesting result regarding the discrete case. I realize that this is just a partial answer but I feel it is a bit too long to fit in a comment. So let us assume
$$  x =  \frac{2\pi p}{q}, $$
where $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in \{1, 2,  \dots, q - 1\}$. Then the following holds:

1. if $q$ is a prime and $q = 1 \; (\text{mod} \; 4)$, then the series diverges
2. if $q$ is a prime and $q = 3 \; (\text{mod} \; 4)$, then the series converges

In particular, the set of $x$ such that the series diverges is dense in $(0, 2\pi)$. To prove this, denote
$$  \Delta :=  \sum_{n = 1}^{q} \cos(n^2x). $$
Now, thanks to $q$-periodicity, we can easily see that the series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left[\cos(n^2x) - \frac{\Delta}{q}\right] $$
has bounded partial sums and hence by Dirichlet test, the series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2x)}{n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\left[ \cos(n^2x) - \frac{\Delta}{q}\right]  + \frac{\Delta}{q}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$
converges if and only if $\Delta = 0$. (This trick does not work when $x$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$.) Next, we will need some basic number theory. Suppose that $q$ is an odd prime and define:
$$\zeta := e^{ix}$$
$$ \phi(z) := z^{q - 1} + z^{q - 2} + \dots + 1, $$
$$ h(z) := \sum_{m = 1}^{q-1}\left(\frac{m}{q}\right)z^n, $$
where
$$ \left(\frac{m}{q}\right)$$
is the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol). Since $q$ is a prime, the [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) modulo $q$ is cyclic. From the cyclic structure, it follows that each nonzero quadratic residue of $q$ is present in the sequence $1,4,9, \dots, (q-1)^2$ exactly twice. Hence
\begin{align} \Delta  &=  1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{q-1} \cos(n^2x),\\
 &=  1 + 2\sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times \; \wedge \; \left(\frac{m}{q}\right) = 1} \cos(mx),\\
 &  =  1 + 2\sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times \; \wedge \; \left(\frac{m}{q}\right) = 1} \Re{(\zeta^m)} - \phi(\zeta),\\
 & = \Re{(h(\zeta))}. \end{align}
Note that $h(\zeta) \neq 0$ (this follows from the fact that $\zeta$ is already a root of an irreducible polynomial $\phi$ and from the observation that $h$ is clearly not divisible by $\phi$). Finally, we observe that
\begin{align}
 h(\zeta) &= \sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times} \left(\frac{m}{q}\right)\zeta^m\\
  &= \sum_{m \in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times} \left(\frac{-m}{q}\right)\zeta^{-m}\\
  &= \left(\frac{-1}{q}\right)\overline{h}(\zeta).\\
\end{align}
If $q = 1 \; (\text{mod} \; 4)$, then $-1$ is a quadratic residue of $q$ and so $h(\zeta)$ is real. Then $\Delta \neq 0$ and the series will diverge. If $q = 3 \; (\text{mod} \; 4)$, then $-1$ is not a quadratic residue of $q$ and so $h(\zeta)$ is imaginary. Then $\Delta = 0$ and the series will converge. (For analogical sine series, this would be vice versa.)

The following table lists whether the series converges or diverges based on the numerically computed sign of $\Delta$ for different values of $q$ (rows) and $p$ (columns), where

1. symbol $0$ denotes convergence
2. symbol $+$ denotes divergence to $+\infty$
3. symbol $-$ denotes divergence to $-\infty$

[image]

It shows that in the statement above, the assumption of primality is essential and the general case is more complicated. One can expect that the indiscrete case will be yet even more complicated.